# Show ${\rm Hom}(A\times B,C\times D)\cong{\rm Hom}(A,C)\times{\rm Hom}(A,D)\times{\rm Hom}(B,C)\times{\rm Hom}(B,D),$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, book-recommendation, group-homomorphism

For groups $A,B,C$ and $D$ is it true that

$${\rm Hom}(A\times B,C\times D)\cong{\rm Hom}(A, C)\times{\rm Hom}(A, D)\times{\rm
Hom}(B, C)\times{\rm Hom}(B, D),$$

where $\times$ is external direct product. I am searching results related to this. Please suggest to me any book. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If $A,B,C$ are groups, then we have
$$\hom(C,A \times B) \cong \hom(C,A) \times \hom(C,B),$$
but
$$\hom(A \times B,C) \cong \{(f,g) \in \hom(A,C) \times \hom(B,C) : f,g \text{ commute elementwise}\}.$$
here, $f : A \to C$, $g  :B \to C$ commute elementwise if for all $a \in A$ and all $b \in B$ we have
$$f(a) g(b) = g(b) f(a).$$
If $C$ is abelian, this is automatic, so that $ \hom(A \times B,C) \cong \hom(A,C) \times \hom(B,C)$ in that case.

Combining these results gives that $\hom(A \times B,C \times D)$ is isomorphic to the subset of $\hom(A,C) \times \hom(A,D) \times \hom(B,C) \times \hom(B,D)$ of those $(f,g,u,v)$ such that $(f,g) : A \to C \times D$ commutes elementwise with $(u,v) : B \to C \times D$, which means that $f$ commutes elementwise with $u$ and $g$ commutes elementwise with $v$.

As a book recommendation, I would suggest Aluffi's [Algebra: Chapter 0](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-104).

Comment: thank you for answering .... so I can say that if  Groups $A,B,C$ and $D$ are Abelian then $Hom(A\times B,C\times D)\cong Hom(A, C)\times Hom(A, D)\times
Hom(B, C)\times Hom(B, D) $?

Comment: Yes. You only need that $C$ and $D$ are abelian.

Comment: thank you very much sir ...

Comment: Sir I need same type of result for Rings I.e. Hom$(R_1\times R_2, S_1\times S_2)$ for rings $R_1,R_2, S_1,S_2. $Is there also same relation ?

Comment: $\hom(-,S_1 \times S_2)$ works the same (universal property of the product of rings). However, $\hom(R_1 \times R_2,-)$ is more complicated (assuming that our rings and ring homomorphisms are unital by definition, which they should be): If $S$ is commutative, then $$\hom(R_1 \times R_2,S) \cong \{(e,f,g) : e \in S \text{ idempotent}, f \in \hom(R_1,e S), g \in \hom(R_2, (1-e) S)\}.$$
Here, notice that $eS$ is a ring with unit $e$ and that $S \cong eS \times (1-e)S$. If $S$ is not commutative, it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thank you sir ...